# Change anchor tag background color on an onclick event

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to change the background color when the hyperlink is clicked, but since there is an onclick event it appears that the click default behaviour is taken away so the active style does nothing. Would prefer to do this using CSS.

CSS:

```
a.myanchor.sunsetred a:active {      
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <p>
     <a onclick="displayText("Hello world") return false;" href="#" class="myanchor sunsetred">Click to display text</a>
 </p>
```

Any ideas that could help?

Comment: Does the displayText function exist? Will you be using JQuery?

Comment: @TezWingfield yes to both. It is just a function that displays the hello world text as an alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see any difference with or without the onclick parameter. (In Chrome) Just to make sure, you know the `active` state is applied during the click. As soon as you release the mouse button, the state is released. Maybe you mean `:focus` instead.

Either way, I believe you have a syntax error in your style declaration. You are coloring active links **inside other links**, which doesn't make sense. You probably mean:

```
a.myanchor.sunsetred:active {      
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Well spotted :) using :focus is the way to go.